# Can we use private or protected member variables in an interface?

Tags: java

Is it possible to define an interface like this:

```
public interface Test{
   public string name1;
   private String email;
   protected pass;
}
```

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: in some exceptional languages (such as Scala) yes as you are able to define functions within the interface, though in genereally no (such as c#), as you would never be able to access the parametes

Comment: `interface` purpose is to define interface, not state. State is *class* domain. Also `private` means that it will not be accessible directly by subclass so how would you want to access it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is addressed eloquently by the [official Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceDef.html), which the user could have consulted prior to asking.

Comment: I agree, though a language was not specified by the original question

Comment: @McShep that would have made it even a worse question in my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

Having private or protected members in an interface doesn't make sense conceptually. By definition something that is "private" isn't exposed and therefore, anyone consuming the interface would not care if the implementing class had a private email field or not.

Only public members matter to the code consuming the interface.

Comment: though in some languages such as Scala the interface is different as is a trait, so it is possible, but is dependent on langauge, then again... it isnt an interface in that case so no

Comment: @McShep Thanks for the info. I've not written Scala before.

Comment: Is it desirable that member variables used only in methods of the interface are private? (For example, `Random RANDOM = new Random();` is desirable to be initialized only once.)

Answer (score 2):

being java

> only public, static & final are permitted

You should use an `abstract` class instead of an `interface` if you want to declare its fields.